# Default schema in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Thanks to the 'USE' command I can set the default schema; Is there a similar command in order to get the name of the default schema?

Answer (score 9):

`SELECT DATABASE();` should do the trick. Note that this will return `NULL` if there is no schema currently selected.

Answer (score 3):

Mysql provides a function to do this:

```
SELECT database();
```